# AllowHtml Could Not Be Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 and the *AllowHtml* attribute is not being found when I use it in my view model. Please tell me what I am doing wrong because I have searched the internet and it seems as though I am doing everything right.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BckN2.png)

**EDIT: Added Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace StudentGovernment_v2.Models.Bill
{
    public class BillTextEditModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public String Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add a tag relevant to the web-framework you are using, also include the code snippet as text instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've referenced proper version of `System.Web.Mvc` namespace in web.config to use [`AllowHtmlAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.98).aspx). Since the image shows red squiggly line below that namespace, check if web.config files (in project root folder & Views folder) has reference to it depending on MVC version used (I used MVC version 5.0 as example here):

**[Project Root]\web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="true" ...>    
        <namespaces>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
           ...
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
...
<runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

**[Project Root]\Views\web.config**

```
<system.web>
   <pages ...>
   <controls>
     <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
   </controls>
</pages>
```

Then, check References => `System.Web.Mvc` and see "Version" part in Properties window. The version number shown on it must be match with version number in web.config:

[image: System.Web.Mvc namespace]

Afterwards, try cleaning & rebuilding the project, see if red line below `AllowHtmlAttribute` vanishes.